# Cannot log in to the MySQL server in Mac oSX

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

When I browse `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` it shows me a error.

```
 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

And

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this problem

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information about your configuration and instalation? What version of mysql did you install? Did you provide phpmyadmin with user and password? What steps did you take to install phpmyadmin? Cheers.

Comment: I am using version `8.0.18` and Yes I provide username and password also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use terminal command

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Or

Goto your **Syatem Preferences** and find **MySQL** open this tab and click **Start MySQL Server**